# CSS Width Greater then Page Width without Horizontal Scroll (overflow:hidden not an option)

Tags: css

I've got a basic layout going in 960.gs. One line of text is absolutely positioned, starting within an inner DIV and exiting only the right side of the page.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

The issue is that as the text appears as a series of unbroken words, if the width of the text box doesn't extend beyond the end of the page, it breaks some distance from the edge.

1. overflow: hidden; doesn't do the
   trick because I need to set the
   width wider than the page.
2. float
   won't work because the text can't
   escape the width of the inner DIV.
3. I can't set it outside the inner DIV and just position it there as the same problem will still exist.

The code is basically as simple as:

```
<wrapper (containing) DIV>
   <text stripe DIV>
      <p></p>
   </text stripe DIV>
</ wrapper DIV>
```

I know I've done something like this before and I can't for the life of me remember what I ended up doing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given the markup above:

`div.container { width: auto; overflow: hidden; }`

`p { white-space: pre-wrap; }`

...And then insert several hard returns into the string-of-unbroken-words at tested intervals.

The `width: auto` pair is a placeholder; the computed `width` of that div should equal the width of the page canvas.

Alternatively, you can set your text as an image and apply it as the background of the `div` or paragraph with a repeat value of `no-repeat`.